# Migrating from SQL server to MySQL using pentaho unicode issue

Tags: mysql, sql-server, unicode

I have a problem migrating data from SQL server to MySQL. I have *nvarchar* columns in *SQL server* and am exporting them to a Unicode textfile. But when I am importing the column into an utf-8 table of *MySQL* I get an error for duplicate value: Mysql sees no difference between 'Kaneko, Shûsuke' and 'Kaneko, Shusuke'. I am trying to get these values into a unique column.

What's wrong?
must I use another charset in MySQL?

I also tried converting the textfile to utf8 before importing into MySQL, but still getting the same error.

Comment: If you have a text file that has those distinct values in it, then the source of that file is irrelevant, right? This has nothing to do with SQL Server. It seems to be an issue with MySQL, your schema, or the import tool / command.

Comment: SHow us your table definition

Comment: table is created using following code: CREATE TABLE `directors` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Director` nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Director_UNIQUE` (`Director`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8, collate=utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: You need to use the correct collation. By default SQL Server is Western European rules, Case-insensitive, accent sensitive, but you can change this of course. It looks like MySQL is accent-insensitive by default. You need to set it to an equivalent collation.

Comment: It looks like MySQL doesn't ship with a case-insensitive, accent-sensitive Unicode collation by default. You can add one though: https://mariadb.com/blog/adding-case-insensitive-distinct-unicode-collation I suggest the name utf8_general_ci_as

Comment: i have added my own collation for utf8 charset but joining on these columns is incredible slow...

Comment: indexes solved the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem in your Mysql Table creation. First use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on mysql prompt and see its table structure. Have you used right charset and collate. You can read here [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-charsets.html)

Many times collation is indeed not only case insensitive, but also partly accent insensitive, so ñ = n. (as Joni Salonen points out, this is incorrect!) but `á = a.`

So we can use binary collation but its have own drawback.Binary collation compares your string exactly as strcmp() in C would do, if characters are different (be it just case or diacritics difference). The downside of it that the sort order is not natural.

An example of unnatural sort order (as in "binary" is) : A,B,a,b Natural sort order would be in this case e.g : A,a,B,b (small and capital variations of the sme letter are sorted next to each other)

The practical advantage of binary collation is its speed, as string comparison is very simple/fast. In general case, indexes with binary might not produce expected results for sort, however for exact matches they can be useful. 
Use a binary collation for the specific column (possibly your best bet)

For ex-

```
drop table cc;
CREATE TABLE cc ( c CHAR(100) primary key ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
insert into cc values ( 'Kaneko, Shûsuke' );
insert into cc values ( 'Kaneko, Shusuke' );
```

Comment: show create table directors gives me this: 'CREATE TABLE `directors` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Director` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Director_UNIQUE` (`Director`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6311 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'

Comment: I tried it, no difference still the same error. I am not using pentaho now, just inserting the two values by using sql code, insert into ... values... Why can't i use NVARCHAR in mysql, is it just there for the show??? By-the-way, i am using mysql workbench on windows...

Comment: which language? what do you mean?

Comment: I myself come from the Netherlands, but this data comes from imdb.com... my keyboard is us - international. when i insert é en e it also gives an error...

Comment: Yesss, you're right! Collation utf8_bin solves the problem, thanks a lot Hitesh

Comment: There's is one problem though, joining on these binary columns is very very slow...